# Geoserver Error while publishing a shapefile from a custom PostGIS schema

Tags: postgis, geoserver, coordinate-system, schema-architecture

I have organized my shapefiles in seperate PostGIS's schemas. Also I have added the schemas into the search_path with the following command:

```
ALTER USER postgres SET search_path = custom_schema, public; and
ALTER DATABASE my_db SET search_path = custom_schema, public;
```

When I try to compute the bounds of the layer in GeoServer (compute from data),in order to publish it, it raises the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for potamoi at 
org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:541) at 
org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:431) at 
org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:367) at 
org.vfny.geoserver.global.GeoServerFeatureSource.getBounds(GeoServerFeatureSource.java:660) at 
org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getNativeBounds(CatalogBuilder.java:561) at 
org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getNativeBounds(CatalogBuilder.java:543) at 
org.geoserver.web.data.resource.BasicResourceConfig$1.onSubmit(BasicResourceConfig.java:120) at 
org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:68) at 
org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:143) at 
org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:177) at 
org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:300) at 
org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.BehaviorRequestTarget.processEvents(BehaviorRequestTarget.java:119) at 
org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92) at 
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250) at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329) at 
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436) at 
org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545) at 
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484) 
at 
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:160) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646) 
at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75) at 
org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71) at 
org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71) at 
org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311) at 
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) at 
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) at 
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at 
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at 
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) at 
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at 
org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54) at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geonode.security.GeoNodeCookieProcessingFilter.doFilter(GeoNodeCookieProcessingFilter.java:111) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173) at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for potamoi at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1309) at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:534) ... 111 more 

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "potamoi" does not exist Position: 82 at 
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2062) at 
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1795) at 
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) at 
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:479) at 
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:353) at 
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:252) at 
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208) at        
   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208) at 
   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1285) ... 112 more
```

I think that this is because GeoServer doesn't find the PostGIS's functions which live in public schema.

Is there a way to publish the shapefiles in GeoServer from a custom PostGIS's schema without duplicating the PostGIS's functions in it ?

Comment: Please the code or quote format to [edit] your post to be legible. Note that once a shapefile (or any other source format) is loaded in a database, it becomes a "table" and is no longer in the source format.

Comment: Error occurs before any PostGIS function is needed because GeoServer does not find your table:  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "potamoi" does not exist. What do you mean by "dublicating the PostGIS's functions"? You do not want to run "create_extension postgis" and point the schema with the UI http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/postgis.html?

Answer (score 4):

GeoServer can't find your table `potamoi` - did you set the schema to match your `custom_schema`?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help !

At first, I defined the custom_schema to the Edit "Vector Data Source" page of GeoServer UI as you proposed. 
After that, GeoServer found the table but raised another error:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for schema <custom_schema>

So, I connected as a superuser into my Postgresql and ran the following command:
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA <custom_schema> to my_user;

and problem solved !